# How can I convert the colorspace of an EPS file?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, eps

Is it possible to convert the colorspace of an EPS file from RGB to CMYK or vise versa? I'm looking to create another EPS file with all the fill/stroke/etc. color values converted to the new colorspace equivalent.

Comment: You might find [still.ps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.lang.postscript/still.ps/comp.lang.postscript/F4tFfdmGkZY/Y-qijtWzbGMJ) instructive. A very early version of Distiller, it's a postscript program that executes the input program, and by replacing operators like your other answers describe, produces a re-written postscript program as output. The program was written by the author of the Adobe Green Book and Thinking In Postscript, both free online. Both books may be necessary to fully understand his techniques.

Comment: Understood. This sounds like a fairly intensive process. I will give still.ps a run. I have been reading through the Adobe Green Book and it's an excellent guide. I will give Thinking in Postscript a read as well. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Also you can open the postscript file in illustrator or inkscape for this operation. Might nit be what you'd want to do as some of the pagination operations might not work too well. But those are not available in EPS.